# Implementing image scroll in header of ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview, android-scrollview

I want to implement a list but in the header I want to add a horizontal swipe action to view different images . The rest of my list is just text. 
Something like below.

My question is how I should implement the image viewer/scroller in the header? `HorizontalScrollView` `ImageSwitcher`?`FragmentStatePagerAdapter` I need it to be a seamless scroll with the listview.

Any suggestions?

[image: this]

Comment: Use view flipper and below it list view

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Create separate layout for your header view and then add it your listview header

```
 View headerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(
            R.layout.viewpager, null);
 listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
 listView.addHeaderView(headerView);
```

I hope it will work.

Comment: Yes I know but how should I implement the swipe forimage " R.layout.viewpager"

Comment: Just make a different layout for swiping images --> before setting it in list's header check if it is working perfectly or not --> Inflate this view and set it in list before setting any other data to list.

Comment: @user1163234 user view pageradapter you can swipe it easily

Comment: send me a reference page please?